# Vue v-for changing from version 1 to version 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I'm learning Vue.js and found this fiddle that does exactly what I want to do.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/os7hp1cy/48/

I integrated this and am getting this error:

> invalid expression: v-for="user in users | filterBy searchKey | paginate"

So I've done some digging and I see it has changed from version 1 to 2. However, I don't know how to fix this.

```
<li v-for="user in users | filterBy searchKey | paginate">{{ user.name }}</li>
```

I would like to replace this with something that Vue 2 will support and will work the same way.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html

Answer (score 3):

As of Vue version 2, filters can only be used inside text interpolations (`{{ }} tags`). [See the documentation for migrating from Vue version 1.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html)

You can use a computed property to filter the users and use that computed property in the `v-for` directive instead:

```
computed: {
  filteredUsers: function() {
    let key = this.searchKey.toUpperCase();
    return this.users.filter((user) => {
      return user.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(key) !== -1
    })
  },
  paginatedUsers: function() {
    var list = this.filteredUsers;
    this.resultCount = list.length
    if (this.currentPage >= this.totalPages) {
      this.currentPage = this.totalPages
    }
    var index = this.currentPage * this.itemsPerPage
    return list.slice(index - 1, index - 1 + this.itemsPerPage)
  }
}
```

```html
<li v-for="user in paginatedUsers">{{ user.name }}</li>
```

---

Also, when using `v-for` to generate a range of numbers like you do for your page numbers, [Vue version to starts the index at 1 instead of 0](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#v-for-Range-Values-changed). So, you'll need to update the logic depending on a starting index of 0 as well.

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/b6xvcxLs/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: I tried doing this with 5 results per page and it seems to outputting the first five in index 0. Could possibly have a look as its working with 1 itemsPerPage but not more than that. Thanks! Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b6xvcxLs/1/

Comment: Solved it! here is a working fiddle, it supports more than 1 result and the pagination is correct now. https://jsfiddle.net/b6xvcxLs/1/